# Tree Selection PrimeFaces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Desejo fazer um recurso na aplicação que lista as pastas e os arquivos de um diretório, então pensei no Tree Selection do Primefaces, porém desejo expandir o Tree Selection no nível das pastas e os arquivos serem abertos ao lado com em um frame. Seria um funcionamento como um Explorer do Windows.

Consign fazer isto com o Tree Selection? Existe alguma outra forma de fazer?

Comment: Alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 1):

A idéia é você trazer na sua Tree List somente as pastas e, ao selecionar um item (pasta), você carrega na lateral os arquivos da pasta selecionada utilizando componentes de lista (DataTable ou DataList).

Comment: @MarconcílioSouza isso foi uma sugestão de implementação. Deveria ter colocado código fonte da sugestão?!

Comment: Sim, seria bem melhor

Comment: @MarconcílioSouza só uma dica, talvez a qualidade seja baixa, mas me parece que responde a pergunta, não? Não digo que a resposta não tenha problemas e não deva ser melhorada, mas me parece que o motivo não pode ser "não é uma resposta".

Comment: @HugoLeonardo Pretende melhorar alguma coisa?

Comment: Pois é, foi pedido uma sugestão de como fazer e foi dada a sugestão. Implementar o código seria fazer pro usuário solicitante. A pergunta ta mais pra lógica do que técnica.

Comment: @bigown pretendo sim, fazer o exemplo e postar. Mas como disse, estarei fazendo pra ele e acho que a ideia não é essa.

Comment: @HugoLeonardo concordo que a pergunta também não é das melhores.

Comment: @bigown concordo, mas se for preciso, posso postar a solução completa pra ele.

Comment: Concordo com o @bigown que a pergunta podia ser melhor. Hugo, ou dás uma resposta com tudo explicado e esperamos que seja reconhecida (e votada) ou então dá algumas luzes para o AP não ficar com tudo feito e ter de aprender a resolver os ultimos passos.